# Split Image dataset for keras model.fit_generator

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have single directory, dataset, which contains sub-folders(labels/classes) of images.
Here's the Sub-folders of animal images in dataset:

[image]

I want to split the dataset into train and test set for `model.fit_generotar()`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `glob` to get file paths iterator.

You can then use `scikit-learn`'s train-test split to get train and test data paths (use `stratify` parameter to get the same class distribution in test/train as in whole dataset).

The result would be two lists of paths, which you can write to appropriate test/train folders, and then you can apply generator's `flow_from_directory` method.

EDIT:

The second way  would be to not use `flow_from_directory`, but load train/test sets (either load everything and use `scikit-learn` method or use what I've described before) and then use generator's `flow` method.

Also note that **you might not want to use generators for test/validation data**, since it would make comparing accuracy hard, since you won't have a fixed valid/test set.

Comment: what you are telling that would be correct in case of only one sub-folder of images. In my case, there are 5 sub-folders of images namely lions, rabbits, snakes, dogs, and cats.

Comment: No. Generator uses these folders to assign classes. BTW I've also added a second method you could use.